# Spring Application context with parallel junit tests

Tags: spring-boot, junit, parallel-testing

I tried Junit 5.3 parallel execution for Spring Boot (2.7.12) integration tests.

`junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true`

`junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = same_thread`

`junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent`

The execution time for tests increased, and by the logs I see that Spring application is initiated more frequently (it looks like the context is not cached/reused).

I tried to runs all the classes in the same thread (by putting `same_thread`), using annotations `@Execution(ExecutionMode.SAME_THREAD)` and `@Isolated` over test classes, but it did not help - the context is initiated each time for a new class.
The only thing that helps is setting `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled` back to false.

Is there any ability to reuse Spring Application context for junit tests run in parallel?

Comment: The Spring test context framework uses threadlocals to manage the current `TestContext` if threads get reused or multiple threads operate on the same context configuration it might see multiple cache misses leading to multiple instantiations of 1 configuration combination, leading to it being loaded multiple times (eventually it will be cached but it will take more time).

Comment: Yes, that's expected, but when I put @Isolated or set "junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default =same_thread" - should not it be the single thread anyway?

Comment: Not sure if `@Isolated` would help. Not garantueed. The classes will run now in sequence but the actual tests in the class can use a different thread (not seeing the set thread-local). I'm not sure if parallel execution and stateful tests (as that is what they are) are a good fit.